# How to reverse a sequence of numbers with recursion in java

Tags: java, recursion, numbers, sequence

I'm quite stuck on this piece of code, the assignment is simple: "given a number n or value, print on the console the sequence from n to 1 and from 1 to n (repeating the number 1 so it should be like this '5432112345').

The recursion per se is not a problem, the real problem is the second part due to the fact that i cannot use any other variable only n. I cannot store the starting value nowhere, since each time i call the method it would be actualized.

Here is the code so far:

```
public int mirrorRecursive(Integer value){
       if (value < 1){        //in case the given value is less than 1 it won't print anything
            return value;
        }
        if(value == 1){        //in case the value is 1, it will be printed and stop the calling
            System.out.print(value);
        }else{                 //in case the value is not 1 or less, it will print and call again the method
            System.out.print(value);
            mirrorRecursive(--value);
        }

        return value;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't really use Stackoverflow to solve classroom assignments.

Comment: Actually i think is a good tool to use, either you are a student or a professional programmer. It's not  always easy to understand a concept, or maybe you just miss a simple step. Everyone has the right to ask and sound stupid, if the purpose is to learn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what's the use of the value returned by the method, but in order to print the desired output, all you need is:

```
public static int mirrorRecursive(Integer value){
  System.out.print(value);
  if (value > 1) {
    mirrorRecursive(value - 1);
  }
  System.out.print(value);

  return value;
}
```

i.e. print the current number before and after the recursive call, and make a recursive call as long as `value` > `1`.

Comment: This is the answer, but I don't think that in stackoverflow we should solve homework assignments ;-)
And as an improvement the method can be void.